# Object method loses its scope when called using setInterval

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to print out the value of the array `players` like in the example below? I've tried to find a solution for hours now...

```
function Room(name, id, owner) {
    this.players = [];
    this.movementz =  function() {
        console.log(this.players);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function using `setInterval`, like this:

```
setInterval(room.movementz, 1000);
```

Comment: Should work. How do you call that method. _And: how do you create the object you call the method on._ Note: there's a typo in the fucntion name, perhaps.

Comment: have you tried running it yourself? I'm calling it through set interval(movementz,100).

Comment: _*sigh*_ Please add this to your post. What do you want to do, what do you expect, what's the result instead. I ran `var r = new Room(); r.movementz() // and got [] as I expected`

Comment: hmm, most be some problem with setinterval(movementz,100), since i get the expected result when just calling it normally.

Comment: When `setinterval()` calls `movementz()`, it probably doesn't have the context (`this`) you expect. See [The "this" problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval#The_.22this.22_problem).

Comment: finally fixed it with:  var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){ that.movements() }, 100)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is about the `this` object: creating your object and manually calling it's `movementz` method will work because the `this` element is the object itself, but **using `setInterval` will cause the method to be called with `this === window`**.

Here is an example:

```
var room = new Room();

room.movementz(); // []
setInterval(room.movementz, 1000); // undefined
```

This happens because when the `movementz` method gets called by `setInterval`, the `this` object is `window`, so, to fix this, **you'll have to force the function to be called using `room` as `this`**. You can easily accomplish this **using the `bind` method**, here's an example:

```
var room = new Room(),
    players = "hello";

setInterval(room.movementz, 1000);
// this will output "hello" because this === window

setInterval(room.movementz.bind(room), 1000);
// this will output [], because now this === room
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Marco, this had me stumped a while.